# Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WD_BREAK'

Tags: python, docx, attributeerror

Here is my code:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph('This is on first page!')
doc.paragraphs[0].runs[0].add_break(docx.text.WD_BREAK.PAGE)
doc.add_paragraph('This is on the second page!')
doc.save('twoPage.docx')
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WD_BREAK'
```

Answer (score 7):

[Breaks](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html?highlight=WD_BREAK.PAGE#docx.text.run.Run.add_break) are included in `docx.enum.text`. You should change

```
docx.text.WD_BREAK.PAGE
```

to

```
docx.enum.text.WD_BREAK.PAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

***python3.7***

```
import docx
from docx.text.run import *
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph('This is on first page!')
doc.paragraphs[0].runs[0].add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
doc.add_paragraph('This is on the second page!')
doc.save('twoPage.docx')
```

***or***

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph('This is on first page!')
doc.paragraphs[0].runs[0].add_break(docx.text.run.WD_BREAK.PAGE)
doc.add_paragraph('This is on the second page!')
doc.save('twoPage.docx')
```